# How can I add a parent element to a group of paragraph?

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="description">
  <h5>Title</h5>
  <p>First paragraph</p>
  <p>Second paragraph</p>
  <p>Third paragraph</p>
</div>
```

I want to insert, with jQuery, a parent element for all `<p>` elements, except the first one. So the HTML that I would like to generate is this:

```
<div id="description">
  <h5>Title</h5>
  <p>First paragraph</p>
  <div class="details">
    <p>Second paragraph</p>
    <p>Third paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

There's the `.wrap()` function in jQuery that can add a parent, but if I use it like this:

```
$("#description p:not(:first)").wrap('<div class="details" />');
```

It wraps all my `<p>` individually.

Is there any way I can modify my selector to put my `<div>` around the "group" instead? Or maybe it's easier using a different function that is yet unknown to me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So you are looking for the `.wrapAll()` method.

```
$("#description p").not(":first").wrapAll('<div class="details" />');
```

Ref.: [.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/)

Comment: Nice! Clean and easy solution! Thank you jAndy! One subquestion: is there a reason why you wrote the selector using .not() instead of :not? (I learn jQuery by myself so if there's a subtlety there, I don't know about it.) Thanks again!

Comment: @Gabriel: It is in general faster to use methods for reducing a "wrapped set" of nodes. By using the `:not()` notation, `Sizzle` (John Resigs css query engine) has to do the job. And that on the other hand, is slower in most situations.