# How to wrap DIV tags with different class names?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, parent-child, jquery-traversing

> **Duplicate:**
>   [How can I add a parent element to a group of paragraph?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3542779)

I have the following HTML blocks repeated in the document

```
<!-- first block -->
<div class="first">
   My first div
</div>
<div class="second">
   My second div
</div>

<!-- second block -->
<div class="first">
   My first div
</div>
<div class="second">
   My second div
</div>

...
```

How can I wrap the Divs with jQuery to get the resulting HTML like this...

```
<!-- first block -->
<div class="container">
   <div class="first">
      My first div
   </div>    
   <div class="second">
      My second div
   </div>
</div>

<!-- second block -->
<div class="container">
   <div class="first">
      My first div
   </div>    
   <div class="second">
      My second div
   </div>
</div>

...
```

Comment: same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542779/how-can-i-add-a-parent-element-to-a-group-of-paragraph

Comment: Your edit markedly changes the question. `wrapAll` continues to be how you do it, it's just down to how you select what to wrap. I've updated [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13877785/157247) with two examples of ways to do it, depending on how your blocks are organized. That should get you pointed in the right direction, even if your specific structure doesn't happen to fit either of the examples.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're in luck, that's exactly what [`wrapAll`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) is for:

```
$(".first, .second").wrapAll('<div class="container"></div>');
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ebuveh/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ebuveh/1/edit)

---

Your edit *markedly* changes the question. If you need to do the above only *within* some containing block, you can loop through the containing blocks and apply `wrapAll` only to their contents. You'll need a way to identify the way you want to group your divs, which you haven't specified in the question.

If the divs have some kind of container around them, you can do this:

```
$(".block").each(function() {
  $(this).find(".first, .second").wrapAll('<div class="container"></div>');
});
```

In that example, I've assumed the divs are within a container with the class `"block"`.

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ebuveh/5) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ebuveh/5/edit)

If there's no structural way to identify them, you'll have to do it some other way. For instance, here we do it by assuming any time we see a `first`, we should stop grouping:

```
var current = $();

$(".first, .second").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.hasClass('first')) {
    doTheWrap(current);
    current = $();
  }
  current = current.add(this);
});
doTheWrap(current);

function doTheWrap(d) {
  d.wrapAll('<div class="container"></div>');
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ebuveh/6) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ebuveh/6/edit)

That works because `$()` gives you the elements in *document order*, so if we loop through them in order, saving them up, and then wrap up the previous ones whenever we see a new `first` (and of course, clean up at the end), you get the desired result.

Or here's another way to do that same thing, which doesn't use `wrapAll`. It relies on the *first* matched element being a `first` (so no `second`s before `first`s!):

```
var current;

$(".first, .second").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.hasClass('first')) {
    current = $('<div class="container"></div>').insertBefore(this);
  }
  current.append(this);
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ebuveh/7) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ebuveh/7/edit)

Comment: Oh... I didn't knew wrapAll... +1

Comment: Yes, my edit it was changing the question, so I reposted the question and I got another smart solution in one line of code in jQuery at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878539/how-to-wrap-multiple-div-blocks-with-different-class-names-in-jquery

Comment: Great examples, very useful.

Comment: @Max: Thanks! Glad that helped! (I don't see any "one line" answers there, FWIW.)

Answer (score 3):

```
$('div').wrapAll('<div class="container" />');
```

would do it, but that would also wrap any other divs so perhaps:

```
$('.first, .second').wrapAll('<div class="container" />');
```

is better.

Comment: No, `wrap` will wrap them *individually*. (Each will get its own container div.)

Comment: wrap() and wrapAll() do not work: wrap() method wrap each Div, and wrapAll() wrap all the blocks together. I need a function to wrap each block...

Comment: This will be because you didn't specify exactly what you wanted and have now changed your question!